# Authorization of nested apps within an ASPNET Core 5 app

Tags: authentication, razor-pages, iis-10, staging, asp.net5

I have deployed a staging server under a subdomain and serving it on IIS on a VPS. I published an ASP.NET Core 5 (RazorPages template) app and it is using default identity, requiring login before you can go to any other page. Obviously I want to realize the staging of different applications under this domain so on IIS, I have created a virtual directory under my staging website and pointed it to the physical location where I have deployed the demo app. Physically, the staging website and the demo app are next to each other, but on IIS there is a *virtual directory application* called /demo under the main iis website. "demo" is also an aspnet core mvc app.

When I type in the Url staging.mysite.com/demo it loads and working fine under its own application pool. What I want to achieve is to create a custom route in the main staging website that will be recognised as /demo (as if there was a demo controller or razor page dir) and redirect back to login if the user is not logged in. Right now it loads the demo app no matter the user is signed in or not. Is this even possible to secure child apps from a parent app? I have read so many articles and msdn documentation but obviously lack fundamental knowledge about IIS and the middlewares. I suspect IIS is not even forwarding the request to aspnet middleware/kestrel when it finds an IIS application on that URL. How should I approach this problem? Any leads will be greatly apppreciated.

Edit: I don't want the authentication on the main website to propagate into the child app. Just want to keep unauthorized access to the child app. Child apps have seperate logins and that is fine for now. Thanks.

Comment: Nested applications in ASPNET Core 5 applications should add sub-applications. In IIS, a site can have multiple applications and an application can have multiple virtual directories. If the login code and configuration are deployed to the root default site, then shared authentication will take effect. You can deploy them to different sites separately.

Comment: As a virtual directory, another asp.net core app is working without a problem. Without being physically deployed under the parent app directory, if that's what you mean.